# SQL : condition test

Tags: mysql

I want to test 2 condition on two counters.below the sample:

```
 id_client | zipcode     | timestamp               | UC     | MISS
--------------------------------------------------|--------|------
amar      | 11111       | 2016-09-28 20:05:03.001 | 15     | 0
akbar     | 11111       | 2016-09-28 20:05:03.001 | 50     | 1  
antony    | 11111       | 2016-09-28 20:07:03.001 | 110    | 0
amar      | 11111       | 2016-09-28 20:08:03.001 | 5      | 1

select
  date (CollectionTime) as dates,
  id_client
  case when UC <=15 THEN 'TB'
    UC < 15 THEN 'TB'
    UC > 15  AND UC <=40 THEN 'B'
    UC >40  AND  UC <=80 THEN 'M'
    UC > 80 THEN 'TM'
    ELSE 'NULL' END AS tranche_UC
  case when MISS = O THEN 'BONNE'
  MISS =1 THEN 'Mauvaise'
  ELSE 'NULL' END AS note
from cm_stat 
group by id_client
order by dates;
```

i' expected to have

```
id_clien  | zipcode     | timestamp               | trancheUC    | MISS
--------------------------------------------------|--------      |------
amar      | 11111       | 2016-09-28 20:05:03.001 | TB           | 0
akbar     | 11111       | 2016-09-28 20:05:03.001 | M            | 1  
antony    | 11111       | 2016-09-28 20:07:03.001 | TM           | 0
amar      | 11111       | 2016-09-28 20:08:03.001 | TB           | 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Your query suggests that you want the last column to be `bonne` or `mauvais` and not 1 or 0, as the sample shows. I'll go with bonne and mauvais.

First off you have some syntax errors:

1. missing comma after `id_client`
2. need a `WHEN` for every condition in `CASE`

Here's the query without the syntax errors:

```
select
  date (CollectionTime) as dates,
  id_client, -- missing comma
  case
    when UC <=15 THEN 'TB'
    when UC < 15 THEN 'TB' -- needed WHEN (use before every condition)
    when UC > 15  AND UC <=40 THEN 'B' -- needed WHEN
    when UC >40  AND  UC <=80 THEN 'M' -- needed WHEN
    when UC > 80 THEN 'TM' -- needed WHEN
    ELSE 'NULL' END AS tranche_UC
  case
    when MISS = O THEN 'BONNE'
    when MISS =1 THEN 'Mauvaise' -- needed WHEN
    ELSE 'NULL' END AS note
from cm_stat 
group by id_client
order by dates;
```

Now that the syntax is all set, you have some logic errors:

1. the `UC` logic is overdone (example, checking for <= 15 *and* < 15 to return `TB`)
2. I don't understand why you have `group by id_client`

So here's the query with the logic straightened out:

```
select
  date (CollectionTime) as dates,
  id_client,
  case
    when UC <=15 THEN 'TB'
    when UC <=40 THEN 'B'
    when UC <=80 THEN 'M'
    when UC > 80 THEN 'TM'
    ELSE 'NULL' END AS tranche_UC
  case
    when MISS = O THEN 'BONNE'
    when MISS = 1 THEN 'Mauvaise'
    ELSE 'NULL' END AS note
from cm_stat
order by dates;
```